# Summarising values in dplyr - Crashes RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, dplyr

Can `dplyr` perform chained `summarise` operations on a `data.frame`?

My data.frame has the structure:

```
data_df = tbl_df(data)    
data_df %.%
        group_by(col_1) %.%
        summarise(number_of= length(col_2)) %.%
        summarise(sum_of = sum(col_3))
```

This causes RStudio to encounter a `fatal error - R Session Aborted` message

Usually with `plyr` I would include these `summarise` functions without problems.

**UPDATE**

Data are [here.](https://github.com/johnmarquess/some.data/blob/master/orth0106.csv)

Code is:

```
library(dplyr)

orth <- read.csv('orth0106.csv')
orth_df = tbl_df(orth)


orth_df %.%
    group_by(Hospital) %.%
    summarise(Procs = length(Procedure)) %.%
    summarise(SSIs = sum(SSI))
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example, to reproduce the error?

Comment: @martin-bel - data and code now included.

Comment: In the future, please file bugs like this directly at github. I've voted to close this issue since it will no longer apply once the next version of dplyr comes out (which will be soon)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bug report which has been fixed in the development version of the software.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can reproduce the error on Windows 7 machine running RStudio 0.97.551

It may be because you're calling `summarise` and chaining onto something that's not there.  You can `summarise` with 2 different columns as I've done here.

```
url <- "https://raw.github.com/johnmarquess/some.data/master/orth0106.csv"

library(dplyr)

orth <- read.csv(url)
orth_df <- tbl_df(orth)


orth_df %.%
    group_by(Hospital) %.%
    summarise(Procs = length(Procedure), SSIs = sum(SSI))

## Source: local data frame [18 x 3]
## 
##    Hospital Procs SSIs
## 1         A   865   80
## 2         B  1069   38
## 3         C   796   24
## 4         D   891   35
## 5         E   997   39
## 6         F   550   30
## 7         G  2598  128
## 8         H   373   27
## 9         I  1079   70
## 10        J   714   30
## 11        K   477   30
## 12        L   227    2
## 13        M   125    6
## 14        N   589   38
## 15        O   292    3
## 16        P   149    9
## 17        Q  1984   52
## 18        R   351   13
```

In any event this seems like either an RStudio or a `dplyr` bug.  I'd open up an issue with Hadley as he probably cares either way.  https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues

**EDIT** This (your first call) also cause rgui (windows) and the terminal to crash as well on:

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
```

This indicates a `dplyr` problem Hadley and Romain will want to know about.

To get my first point we run:

```
orth_df %.%
    group_by(Hospital) %.%
    summarise(Procs = length(Procedure))

Source: local data frame [18 x 2]

   Hospital Procs
1         A   865
2         B  1069
3         C   796
4         D   891
5         E   997
6         F   550
7         G  2598
8         H   373
9         I  1079
10        J   714
11        K   477
12        L   227
13        M   125
14        N   589
15        O   292
16        P   149
17        Q  1984
18        R   351
```

Where is `%.% summarise(SSIs = sum(SSI))` supposed to find `SSI`?

So the chaining you think is happening fails.  TO my understanding `%.%` isn't exactly like how `ggplot2` works but similar.  In `ggplot2` once you pass the data in the initial mapping you can access it later on.  Here %.% seems to modify grab the left chunk and operate on it like this:

[image]

So you're grabbing:

```
   Hospital Procs
1         A   865
2         B  1069
3         C   796
.
.
.
17        Q  1984
18        R   351
```

when you use `%.% summarise(SSIs = sum(SSI))` and there is no `SSI` to be gotten.  So the analogy that comes to mind is [serial vs. parallel wiring Christmas lights](http://auschristmaslighting.com/wiki/Series_vs_Parallel).  `%.% = serial` `ggplot() + = parallel`.  This is a nonprogrammer's understanding of things and the R gurus may come and tell me I'm stupid but for now that's the best theory you've got.

Comment: DOH! Now I see. Does not exist in the newly created df.

Comment: You're missing the point or not understanding what chaining is. See my latest edit with picture.

Comment: I see that now. Thanks for pointing this out. I will report the bug.

Comment: Thanks for filing the issue. However, I believe it was already fixed in the development version.

Comment: @Romain you are correct.  It now throws an error as I state in the report.

Comment: A quick comment that this happens on Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander), R 3.1 (Spring Dance), dplyr_0.1.3 + Rcpp_0.11.1; IDE = R Studio Server. In fact, a simple summarise() can crash R Studio. If I figure out that it's a dplyr issue rather R Studio issue will report the bug.