# dplyr crashes when using summarise with segfault error

Tags: r, dplyr

my `dplyr` Script sometimes crashes in this code segment:

```
abc.fit <- abc_bySubject %>%
  do(fit = lm(value ~ delta, .)) %>%
  summarise(fvc_intercept = coef(fit)[1],
        fvc_slope = coef(fit)[2])
```

the crash error is:

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x7ff041000098, cause 'memory not mapped'
```

However, it also occur when I execute this part in Rstudio with error `fatal error - R Session Aborted` , but less frequently. It always happens when I source the Script in the R command line.
I tested it on different machines with lots of RAM.
R and all packages are uptodate and I'm using the latest version of Ubuntu.

It may be related to this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347968/summarising-values-in-dplyr-crashes-rstudio) but it says this is fixed.

Perhaps there is a nicer solution

Comment: Without the data (simulated please) this is almost impossible to debug. Can you make a minimal working example?

Comment: I've been having problems with `dplyr-0.4.2` on my setup, so I'm using 0.4.1 with no problems. Can you reproduce the error if you [manually downgrade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082341/installing-older-version-of-r-package) your `dplyr` version?

Comment: @r2evans I really don't like downgrading, do you know if this still happens with the dev version on github?

Comment: Not certain; it's reported as fixed in [1302](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1302) but I'm having trouble compiling it (different than [1306](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1306)). I tried earlier with 0.4.2.9002 and it was not fixed, but that was a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option without using `summarise` (the OP's code works in `dplyr_0.4.1.9000`) to get the expected output would be extracting the `coef` from `lm`, convert it to `list`, change the 'names' of list elements (`setNames`) and convert back to `data.frame` within the `do` environment.

```
library(dplyr)
abc.fit <- abc_bySubject %>%
                do(data.frame(setNames(as.list(coef(lm(value~delta, data=.))),
                            c('fvc_intercept','fvc_slope' ))))

abc.fit
#    Subject fvc_intercept   fvc_slope
#1       1     0.5319503 -0.03147698
#2       2     0.4478791  0.04293860
#3       3     0.4318059 -0.03276570
```

If we need to delete the 'Subject' column, we can `ungroup()` and use `select` to select columns other than 'Subject'

```
abc.fit %>% 
      ungroup() %>%
      select(-Subject)
#  fvc_intercept   fvc_slope
#1     0.5319503 -0.03147698
#2     0.4478791  0.04293860
#3     0.4318059 -0.03276570
```

---

Another option would be `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(abc)`), grouped by the 'Subject' column, we get the coefficients (`coef`) of `lm`, convert to `list` (`as.list`) and set the names of the columns (`setnames`).

```
 library(data.table)
 res <- setnames(setDT(abc)[, as.list(coef(lm(value~delta))),
               by =Subject],2:3, c('fvc_intercept', 'fvc_slope'))[]
 res
 #   Subject fvc_intercept   fvc_slope
 #1:       1     0.5319503 -0.03147698
 #2:       2     0.4478791  0.04293860
 #3:       3     0.4318059 -0.03276570
```

We can subset the columns of interest from 'res'

```
res[,-1, with=FALSE]
#   fvc_intercept   fvc_slope
#1:     0.5319503 -0.03147698
#2:     0.4478791  0.04293860
#3:     0.4318059 -0.03276570
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
abc <- data.frame(Subject= rep(1:3,each=10), delta=rnorm(30), value=runif(30))
abc_bySubject <- group_by(abc, Subject)
```

Comment: thanks, this does indeed seem to fix ist. However it feels that this is a bit slower and it also includes the ID column of abc_SubjectID which I have to delete manually. This is only a minor issue so I'm happy with this solution.

Comment: @spore234 I added the `data.table` option.  It should be fast.

Comment: @spore234 Your code works well with `dplyr_0.4.1.9000`